# Select distinct or select distinct from subquery

Tags: oracle, distinct

Which is better than the two queries below in terms of performance?
 The difference is that the first query uses the distinct directly, and the second one has the first query as the inner query (the records are already filtered before the distinct)
(this is oracle)

```
select distinct t1.f1, t2.f2
from t1, t2
where ...

select distinct f1, f2
from
select *
from t1, t2
where ...
```

Comment: Why don't you try it out for yourself? Take a look at the execution plan produced for each query and see what happens. My guess is that it'll make no difference whatsoever, as Oracle is quite capable of rewriting the query behind the scenes.

Comment: "second one has the first query as the inner query (the records are already filtered before the distinct)" In the first query, the distinct happens after the rows are filtered also, logically at least. The query optimizer is free to re-order stuff as long as it gives the same result as the required logical order which is roughly `from`, `joins`, `where`, `group by`, `having`, `select` and finally `order by`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the subquery expresses the same logic, then they are the same. The subquery will be eliminated by a transformation in the optimiser.